# Book on statistical mechanics (including kinetics) with Maximum Entropy approach

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, resource-recommendations, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium

I am looking for a book on statistical mechanics including non-equilibrium  and kinetic topics. Specifically following the Maximum Entropy approach of information theory (*a la* Jaynes). So far I have read papers on this topic, but I would like to see it all together. Jaynes has a book on probability theory, but he does not go into depth into statistical mechanics there.

What is out there?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you look for a book in English, so the only one I could think of is 50 years old. It is called "Principles of Statistical Mechanics”, it has been authored by Amnon Katz and has been published by W.H. Freeman & Company in 1967. This is a short book (about 180 pages of written material), but very dense and straight to the point. You can look it up in a library.

[https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Statistical-Mechanics-Amnon-Katz/dp/071670319X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/071670319X)

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend to take a look at Leonard Susskind's lectures on YouTube.

For a textbook, I have a recommendation for a formal text that is quite good and well known:

[https://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Mechanics-Third-Edition-Pathria/dp/0123821886](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123821886).

It's a graduate level book, and many professors recommend it, t hough I haven't had enough time to read it in full till now.

Comment: Does it follow the information theory approach?

Comment: It does not follow an IT approach.